# Add a completely different line with every button click

Tags: vb.net

Complete noob to vb.net (and programming in general) here, all I really want is every time I click a button, the number in the textbox is added by 1 but the new number shows up on the next line. Tried to google this a hundred times but nothing really helped.

I don't want to use loops as I don't want all numbers to show up at once, only for the added number to show up after clicking a specific button (on a new line).

```
Public Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

    Dim txtoutput As String = ""
    Dim a As Integer = 1

    txtoutput &= "the value of a =" & a & Environment.NewLine
    a = a + 1

    TextBox1.Text = txtoutput

End Sub
```

Comment: Please share the code that you are using. This will help others understand the problem better. Most likely you are just `textbox.text+=number` instead of `textbox.text = number`

Comment: What have you tried so far? Can you show us some code (a [mcve]). You don't need to post the whole thing, just a small portion. In your case the main thing would be the click handler for your button.

Comment: @sidprasher I have now added the code.

Comment: If you want to add the new line to the existing text then don't you think that you ought to start with the existing text rather than an empty string?

Comment: Also, there's not much use adding 1 to a variable that you never use again.  You need to learn the difference between local variables and member variables.

Comment: @pstrjds I deleted most of my attempts already but I might be able to replicate most of them, but I've tried Loops, which literally do exactly as I want except I don't want all of them to show up at once.

Comment: @jmcilhinney actually I declared the "a" variable on the public class itself so every sub could use it, I just put it inside the sub in case people get confused. (I'm gonna fix that)

Comment: We rather get confused if you don't show us the _exact_ code that you're using :). -- Just change `txtoutput &=` to `TextBox1.Text &=` and you should be good to go.

Comment: Not at all. Programming has its learning curve and it is easy to miss certain details or trains of thought in the beginning (and it is also _very_ easy to overdo simple things ;). Glad I could help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are replacing the Text, you want to append a new line, so you need to do:

```
Private a As Int32 = 0

Public Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    a += 1
    Dim newLine = $"the value of a = {a}"
    TextBox1.Text = TextBox1.Text & Environment.NewLine & newLine
End Sub
```

You also have to use a field and not a local variable if you want to retain the old value and increment it. Otherwise it is reset always to it's inital value.

Comment: Or you can use `TextBox1.AppendText(Environment.NewLine & newLine)`

Comment: `Static` before the a will allow you to declare local preventing other methods from changing your variable and the value is preserved between method calls.

Answer (score 1):

Please try to change dim a to static a

```
Public Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

    Dim txtoutput As String = ""
    Static a As Integer = 1

    txtoutput &= "the value of a =" & a & Environment.NewLine
    a = a + 1

    TextBox1.Text = txtoutput

End Sub
```